# Magento 1.9.4.1 Setting up order IDs for different store views under the same store

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, order-increment

When checking the order increments for some stores i found the following:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| group_name | website_name | store_name | store_id | increment_prefix | increment_last_id | entity_type_code |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 1          | Website 1    | English    |        1 | 1                | 100008323         | order            |
| 1          | Website 1    | English    |        1 | 1                | 100006497         | invoice          |
| 1          | Website 1    | English    |        1 | 1                | 100004841         | shipment         |
| 2          | Website 1    | English    |        1 | 1                | 100000018         | creditmemo       |
| 2          | Website 2    | Dutch      |        2 | 2                | 200000332         | invoice          |
| 2          | Website 2    | Dutch      |        2 | 2                | 200000012         | creditmemo       |
| 2          | Website 2    | Dutch      |        2 | 2                | 200000392         | order            |
| 2          | Website 2    | Dutch      |        2 | 2                | 200000246         | shipment         |
| 3          | Website 3    | English    |        6 | 6                | 600000001         | order            |
| 1          | Website 1    | Dutch      |        7 | 7                | 700001292         | order            |
| 1          | Website 1    | German     |        8 | 8                | 800000002         | order            |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Is it possible to change the order incremental id's of the stores with ID's `7` and `8`, as `100001292` and `100000002` respectively -instead of `700001292` and `800000002`?

The store with ID `1` (which belongs to the same website that contains the stores with IDs `7` and `8`) has orders starting already with `10000XXXX`. Would that pose any issues or is it something that would work out of the box in Magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Change the column **increment_prefix** in the **eav_entity_store** table to the desired values.

Basically, this will helps to identify the ordered store.